# Generate File In GitLab Pipeline and Check if Any Differences to Commited File

Tags: git, graphql, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, pipeline

**How can I generate a file in my CI pipeline and check if there are any differences to an existing committed file?**

My CI pipeline runs on merge requests and has a few jobs that run various scripts.

In my dev environment, I have one script that I use to generate a GraphQL SDK and I run this on my command line and commit before I make a merge request.

```
yarn workspace $WORKSPACE run graphql:gen
```

However sometimes I forget to do this before pushing code up and it can be a bit of a hassle waiting for the pipeline to fail and then making the changes locally and pushing code up again.

So my idea is to create a job that runs the GraphQL SDK generator script in my pipeline, which will generate a new SDK and produce an error if the generated file is different to the committed file in the MR. So far I have the script running but that is all.

```
js-run-graphql-gen: 
  interruptible: true # This allows future runs of this job to cancel previous ones.
  extends: [.js-project-xxxxx.com]
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: "$DEPLOY_xxxx == 'true'"
    # Allow Frontend to be explicitly skipped.
    - if: "$SKIP_FRONTEND == 'true'"
      when: never
    # Create a pipeline if there are changes.
    - changes:
        - xxx/**/*
  script:
    - yarn workspace $WORKSPACE run graphql:gen
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `diff` command in gitlab-ci.yml script section. look like:

```
script:
    - diff source.txt target.txt
    - if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then echo 'not equal'; exit 1; else echo 'equal'; fi;
```